# SQL select HTML5 datetime-local

Tags: sql-server, html, datetime, coldfusion-2016

Using a datetime-local form field, and inserting its value into a SQL 2014 smalldatetime field. When querying the database to populate the form field for editing, I'm using

```
SELECT FORMAT(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss') AS myDate
```

My form field code is:

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="myDate" 
    id="myDate" required 
    value="<cfoutput>#myDate#</cfoutput>">
```

When populating the above form field with this database value, it returns the correct date and time BUT it always indicates AM. EXAMPLE: the value in the database table is 
`2016-11-03 13:09:00` but the value in the form shows as [`11/03/2016 01:09 AM`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4bMa.png)

How can I change my SQL format to accurately populate the form field? It should be 11/03/2016 01:09 **PM**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave the formatting in the front end. However, if you change the hours to uppercase it will give you the time in 24 hour format.

```
SELECT FORMAT(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss') AS myDate
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, and now my SQL formatting returns AM or PM correctly into the form field. Silly cases!  ;)  Thank you, Sean.

Comment: *I would leave the formatting in the front end* Agreed. Generally it is best to leave dates - as date *objects*. Converting them to strings, for presentation, is the job of the front end app, ie CF.